# How to convert symbols/icons to glyphs? in sketch

Tags: fonts, sketch-app, glyphs

I need to know how I can convert symbols/icons to font glyphs in sketch app?
Does anyone know how to do it?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Just right-click the symbol at the place it's being used and choose "Detach from Symbol".

EDIT: Misunderstood the original question. If an icon font is what you want, here's a tutorial for that: https://medium.com/sketch-app-sources/font-icons-workflow-with-sketch-and-grunt-16b161d97c5e#.vwumravuc

Comment: this just makes it a standalone vector file. not a font glyph.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. Thanks for adding the clarifying "font glyph". I reworked my answer accordingly.